# Revisions of svn dump

Tags: svn, dump, svnadmin

I have a dump file dump.svn
This dump file includes the revision 0 to 2879
When i load it

```
svnadmin load /path/to/new/repository < /path/to/dump.svn
```

I have a corrupted revision (1174) , so loading it failed .
How to load only the revisions 1175 to 2879 in my new server.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't load just the revision 1175 and higher, because they are stored as changed based on the earlier versions.

Is it possible to fix the original repository with `svnadmin recover $REPOS`?

Comment: i will try but you confirm it , i cant dump just the part i want using the full dumping one. What can i do with this dump ?
Nothing ?

Comment: you can try to contact the subversion user list. Do you only have the dump file, or also a repository that contains all revisions?

Comment: I will try to contact my admnin.
Thank you for your help guys.